# Annotated Entity Validation does not work with FormFactory class

Tags: symfony

I've created a form with two entities, using AcmePizzaBundle's code as an example.

I have `MyBundle/Entity/Factory/UploadFactory.php` which is a factory class for the form. In addition to the two entities (User and Video) there's a third UploadType.php form class:

```
// MyBundle/Form/Type/UploadType.php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('user', new UserType())
            ->add('video', new VideoType());
}
```

`UserType()` and `VideoType()` are form types classes, and hold the necessary fields from their respective entities.

The above is called from a controller/method:

```
public function indexAction(){
  // create upload
  $factory = new UploadFactory();

  $form = $this->createForm(new UploadType(), $factory);
}
```

The User and Video entities have annotated validation. This worked fine before merged the two forms, but now there is no server side validation.

I assume that the validation is not carried through, is there a way to force this?

The code was 'inspired' by the pizza bundle's code https://github.com/beberlei/AcmePizzaBundle/blob/master/Entity/Factory/OrderFactory.php

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
$factory = new UploadFactory();
var_dump($factory);

// gives...
object(Project\MyBundle\Entity\Factory\UploadFactory)#101 (3) {
  ["user":"Project\MyBundle\Entity\Factory\UploadFactory":private]=> NULL
  ["video":"Project\MyBundle\Entity\Factory\UploadFactory":private]=> NULL 
}
```

Comment: What object do you pass as data to your Form ? Does it have a User user property and a Video video property ?

Comment: Both `UserType()` and `VideoType()` are form type classes.

Comment: I'm not talking about Form but data passed to the Form. Can you show us the code calling UploadType ?

Comment: Hope the edit answers your question. It's just standard symfony2 stuff

Comment: Ok, so now : var_dump($factory) ? It must have public (or public getter) "user" and "video" properties, respectively instances of User and Video entities.

Comment: OK, `["video":"Project\MyBundle\Entity\Factory\UploadFactory":private]=> NULL}`, the properties are private, and the getters public. I've changed these values but still the same.

Comment: Paste it in the answer please, but this looks wrong..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27780/discussion-between-mei-and-pece)